# Bypass Capacitor

Tags: bypass-capacitor, calculation

This is a very general question, how to calculate the capacitance needed for a bypass capacitor?
Is there a rule of thumb because I usually find values like 0.1uF for high-frequency bypass caps.

Comment: Does this answer help you: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/274356/173919

Comment: This may help: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/672807/decoupling-capacitor-package-0603-vs-0201

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on source impedance and how much voltage swing or drop you can accept.

As a first order approximation, assume infinite source impedance and calculate how much voltage drop you will get from one switch or clock cycle, depending on application according to ΔV=I*t/C. How much voltage drop you can accept varies from one application to another. I tend to assume 5% as a first back-of-the-envelope calculation for capacitor size. If you end up with less than 100 nF (unless for RF or very fast digital logic), use 100 nF unless you are very short on PCB space.

As pointed out by Justme in the comments, the next thing to consider is ESL. A 100 nF electrolytic or very large plastic film capacitor will have enough capacitance for many applications but fail short due to high inductance due to both internal construction and lead spacing, causing long PCB tracks adding more inductance. This is often referred to as "slow" versus "fast" capacitors. Use as physically small capacitors with as good dielectric as you can afford which still meets your voltage and capacitance requirements.

In the best case, you will have Vcc and GND solid inner planes sandwiched in your PCB with capacitors all over your board, causing very low source impedance in the first place, making each IC or sub-circuit less dependent on local decoupling. Measure your design with spring clip on your oscilloscope probe. If ruler flat under worst case switching, you are good to go. The bean counters at your company/client may have something to say about cost, at which point you may need to scale back to just being acceptable.

Comment: That is only one way to look at the problem, and like said, only first order look. A 100nF cap could be perfectly OK for a 10 MHz MCU, but might not for a 500 MHz MCU. And the 10 MHz MCU could gulp current in short spikes so the burst is much higher frequency and only taken at 10 MHz. For high frequency bypassing, a smaller capacitor (both in physical size and capacitance) will be more effective than a 100nF.

Comment: @Justme Indeed, ESL will become a significant factor at high frequencies. As OP asked about general, I assumed <GHz frequencies.

Comment: Indeed. Even a logic IC, when toggling at 1 Hz, can drive a 50pF load to 0V and 5V in less than 1ns, will take more than 250mA during the transition, so both the current spike is high and duration low, so there are high frequencies far beyond GHz in the waveform.